# PRId16 expanding to d

Tags: c++

I'm reading [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and it's written that

> If one of the strings has an encoding prefix and the other doesn't, the one that doesn't will be considered to have the same encoding prefix as the other.

```
   L"Δx = %" PRId16 // at phase 4, PRId16 expands to "d"
                    // at phase 6, L"Δx = %" and "d" form L"Δx = %d"
```

> If a UTF-8 string literal and a wide string literal are side by side, the program is ill-formed.

Why does `PRId16` expands to `d`?? Where is this defined?

Comment: To be clear,  it expands to `"d"` (on your system anyway), not `d` as you say in the last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C99 (and onward) language standard, as part of `<inttypes.h>`:

> **[7.8.1]** Each of the following object-like macros expands to a character string literal containing a conversion specifier, possibly modified by a length modifier, suitable for use within the format argument of a formatted input/output function when converting the corresponding integer type. These macro names have the general form of `PRI` [...]

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) for an online reference.

The C++ standard inherits C's standard library, so the above can be found in `<cinttypes>`.